# How detect wrong geometry

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

With my table

```
CREATE TABLE map.vzla_seg
(
  seg_id serial NOT NULL,
  link_id bigint,
  geom geometry(LineString),
  sentido integer,
  azimuth integer
)
```

If I do this query

```
SELECT ST_GeometryType  (geom), COUNT(*)
FROM map.vzla_seg
GROUP BY ST_GeometryType  (geom)
```

`ST_GeometryType`  return a `text` so I get:

[image]

But then I get error if I do:

```
SELECT *
FROM map.vzla_seg
WHERE ST_GeometryType  (geom) <> 'ST_LineString'


ERROR:  Unknown geometry type: 0 - Unknown
********** Error **********

ERROR: Unknown geometry type: 0 - Unknown
SQL state: XX000
```

**So how a function works ok in a `GROUP BY` but doesn't work on a `WHERE`**

I'm trying to get the wrong rows to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `geom` from the `SELECT`

```
SELECT seg_id serial, link_id, -- geom geometry(LineString),
       sentido, azimuth,
       ST_GeometryType  (geom)
FROM map.vzla_seg
WHERE ST_GeometryType  (geom) <> 'ST_LineString'
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this actually answers your question or understand how this can be useful anywhere else.

Comment: @EvanCarroll The problem was with `SELECT *`  field `geom` is part of the select and that fail.  Removing the `geom` allow see the id of the bad rows.

Comment: I want to know how they got in there to begin with if the field is marked as `geom` and what they are.

Comment: @EvanCarroll That I dont know. I make a function to create the segments from the original links. They should be only `LineString` And just found out some errors ...  after some digging found out those weirds geometry. Btw I saw your Facebook video. Im from Venezuela Thanks for share it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some of your geometries are missing SRID or have invalid SRID.

use this

```
SELECT * 
FROM map.vzla_seg 
WHERE ST_GeometryType  (ST_SetSRID(geom,4326)) <>'ST_LineString'
```

I used 4326 as example. You should use your own SRID

Comment: Thanks and Welcome to StackOverflow, did you create an account just for me?

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Not specifically but your question happened to be the first question that I answered :)

Comment: The problem is if you include `geom` as part of the `SELECT` you still get an error.